# How can I store a set of concrete components and implement "GetComponent<T>()?"

Tags: architecture, unity, component-based

I would like an abstract class, AbstractComponentAggregate, which has many AbstractComponents.  Users of my framework will create their components by extending AbstractComponent and appending the component to this AbstractComponentAggregate.

I would like to know if there is an elegant way to have AbstractComponentAggregate to store a dictionary of the concrete classes that extend AbstractComponents.  Note, that I want to store many *concrete* classes, each of which is an AbstractComponent.  This is different than storing a list of AbstractComponents.

Thus, you can invoke a method on AbstractComponentAggregate, such as:

AbstractComponentAggregate.GetComponent(), which returns type T.  T is the concrete class, and we ensure T is of type AbstractComponent.

Something similar to this is done in Unity3d, and I would like to emulate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to know if there is an elegant way to have
>   AbstractComponentAggregate to store a dictionary of the concrete
>   classes that extend AbstractComponents. Note, that I want to store
>   many concrete classes, each of which is an AbstractComponent. This is
>   different than storing a list of AbstractComponents.

Assuming the type of your dictionary key is `K`, then `Dictionary<K, AbstractComponent>` will allow you to store instances of concrete AbstractComponent subclasses (such as `FooComponent` and `BarComponent`):

```
var items = new Dictionary<K, AbstractComponent>();
items[K0] = new FooComponent();
items[K1] = new BarComponent();
```

`GetComponent` can look something like:

```
public T GetComponent<T>() {
   // I'm assuming T's type is the dictionary key here.
   AbstractComponent result;
   if(!items.TryGetValue( typeof(T), out result ) ) {
       // Fail here, perhaps with an exception?
   }

   return (T)result;
}
```

This would raise an `InvalidCastException` if the `AbstractComponent` wasn't really an instance of the concrete class `T`. You could use `GetType()` on the result variable and compare the types directly if you wanted to raise a more user-friendly exception.

The code sample assumes you're talking about C#, but the concepts in general are transferable.

Comment: Thanks, Josh.  I guess my brain wasn't functioning this morning.

Comment: I should mention that I am using C++, which made this problem non-trivial.  However, using `boost::any` I was able to emulate C#'s functionality of `Type`. In conjunction with `boost::any_cast` and `boost::any_bad_cast`, I was able to solve the problem.  I believe using `boost::variant` might be a better solution as it can emulate Java's wildcard abilities; however I'll look into that in a later date.  For now, I might throw in some `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERTS` about `T` to ensure it is of type `Component`.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. It's a primitive version of the Implementation I used in [Duality](https://code.google.com/p/duality/) which is more or less inspired by Unity.

```
public sealed class GameObject
{
    private Dictionary<Type,Component> compMap = new Dictionary<Type,Component>();


    public T GetComponent<T>() where T : Component
    {
        return GetComponent(typeof(T)) as T;
    }
    public Component GetComponent(Type t)
    {
        Component result;
        if (this.compMap.TryGetValue(t, out result))
            return result;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public T AddComponent<T>() where T : Component, new()
    {
        if (this.compMap.ContainsKey(typeof(T))) return this.compMap[typeof(T)] as T;
        T newComp = new T();
        return this.AddComponent<T>(newComp);
    }
    public Component AddComponent(Type t)
    {
        if (!typeof(Component).IsAssignableFrom(t)) return null;
        if (this.compMap.ContainsKey(t)) return this.compMap[t];
        Component newComp = Activator.CreateInstance(t, true) as Component;
        return this.AddComponent<Component>(newComp);
    }
    public T AddComponent<T>(T newComp) where T : Component
    {
        Type cType = newComp.GetType();
        if (this.compMap.ContainsKey(cType)) return this.compMap[cType] as T;

        this.compMap.Add(cType, newComp);

        return newComp;
    }
    public T RemoveComponent<T>() where T : Component
    {
        return this.RemoveComponent(typeof(T)) as T;
    }
    public Component RemoveComponent(Type t)
    {
        Component cmp = this.GetComponent(t);
        if (cmp != null) this.RemoveComponent(cmp);
        return cmp;
    }
    public void RemoveComponent(Component cmp)
    {
        this.compMap.Remove(cmp.GetType());
    }
    public void ClearComponents()
    {
        this.compMap.Clear();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.